# MVVM constructors with different parameters call ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm sitting with MVVM code and it all works independently of each other, but I'm going to connect it together.

The problem is I can not call GameViewModel, which is due to different parameters in constructors.

It seems to be a simple problem, but I have not been able to find a solution.

**Casino Player (names and coins must be given to the blackjack player)**

string name;
    int chips;

```
public Player(string n, int c)
{
    name = n;
    chips = c;
}
```

**BlackJack Player**

```
  public BlackJackPlayer(string name, int money, BitmapImage backSide, int currentImage)
    {
        Images = new List<Image>();
        Name = name;
        Money = money;
        ImageBack = backSide;
        CurrentImage = currentImage;
    }
```

**GameViewModel.cs (
Think the problem lies in this class as I want to put casino players names and coins to blackjackplayer)**

```
public GameViewModel(IView view, string name)
    {
        View = view;
        Random = new Random();
        Commands = new Commands(this);

        BlackJackPlayer = new BlackJackPlayer(name, 1000, ImagesHelper.CreateImage("player"), 2);
        BlackJackPlayer.CreateSplitDeck();
        view.AddSplitDeckCards(BlackJackPlayer);
        Computer = new BlackJackPlayer("Computer", 1000, ImagesHelper.CreateImage("computer"), 2);
        view.DisplayMoney(BlackJackPlayer, Computer);
        view.DisplayName(name);

        CardImages = ImagesHelper.GetBlackJackCards();
        view.AddCards(BlackJackPlayer, Computer);
        BlackJackPlayer.ShowBackside();
        Computer.ShowBackside();
        BetAmount = "100";
    }
```

**BlackJackScreen.Xaml.cs (Here I try to access GameViewModel, but of course it is not possible as there are different parameters --> p is a type of player and i must be a string) --> **

```
  public BlackjackScreen(Player p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _player = p;
        defaultButtons = new[] { Hit, Stand, Split };
        splitButtons = new[] { HitLeft, HitRight, StandLeft, StandRight };
        DataContext = new GameViewModel(this, p);
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs (
This is the way I call the different windows that I use, which works fine with the exception of blackJackScreen)**

```
    public void SetContent(Player p, int contentId)
    {
        switch (contentId)
        {
            case 0: ContentHolder.Content = new GamePicker(p); break;
            case 1: ContentHolder.Content = new BlackjackScreen(p); break;
            //case 2: ContentHolder.Content = new SlotsScreen(p); break;
            //case 3: ContentHolder.Content = new VideoPokerScreen(p); break;
            //case 4: ContentHolder.Content = new RouletteScreen(p); break;
        }
    }
```

I sincerely hope that you will give a code example of how this can be solved.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Throw out everything you've done and start again, this is not MVVM. I would recommend tracking down a copy of [John Smith's book Advanced MVVM](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/).

Comment: Yeah, this isn't MVVM as you look to be doing code behind which is a cardinal sin in the MVVM world. This is the wiki definition - [Wiki MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)
Here's a link to a tutorial (just one I found from a quick Google) - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/